# Copy digits from each line at position 2 to 4 to position 8 to 10 for every line using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a shell script which read the input file below and appends the digits that are present at index 2 to 4 in each line to index 8 to 10 in each line.

Input file (input.txt)

```
1234567
1278980
54279
```

Output file: (note the digits at position 2-4 in each line have been appended to the position 8-10 in the same line)
Output.txt

```
1234567234
1278980278
54279  427
```

My current code is shown below. In this code, I am able to only extract the digits at index 2 to 4 of each line but not able to append it to index 8 to 10 for each line in the same file.

```
awk '{val=substr($0,2,3)} (val+0)>=0 {print $0}' input.txt  > filtered_digits.txt
```

May someone help me to achieve this in the same script code?

Thank you to all.

Comment: `(val+0)>=0`? Why? `index 2 to 4` your output suggest you want 3 characters, your awk suggest you want 2 characters. So index 2 to 4 inclusive?

Comment: Yes index 2 to 4 inclusive. I updated the code in the question. I want to be able to update the same input.txt file and create the output.txt file

Answer (score 0):

It's just:

```
awk '{val=substr($0,2,3)} {print $0 val}'
awk '{print $0 substr($0,2,3)}'
# even just (with nonempty input):
awk '$0 = $0 substr($0,2,3)'
```

or with sed:

```
sed 's/\(..\(...\)..\)/\1\2/'
```

> But if I have a line with just 4 characters

You could left align the `$0` with spaces up to 7:

```
awk '$0 = sprintf("%-7s", $0) substr($0,2,3)'
```

Comment: I want to append it starting at index 8 to 10. I am not sure I understand on how you code take that into consideration? May you please explain?

Comment: May you please answer?

Comment: Your input file has 7 characters, so I just suffix it.

Comment: But if I have a line with just 4 characters, then the suffix method wont be working. right? That is the issue I am also facing as I want do the the spacing in the awk cmd as well

Answer (score 0):

When you like to format your output like

```
printf "%-7s%s\n" 12345 123
12345  123
```

You can use

```
sed -r 's/.(..).*/printf "%-7s%s\n" "&" "\1"/e' input.txt
```